# function call works on one element but not the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im getting undefined tmp from slider change but not on button click. Both should give the same output but it is not the case. Here is how my work looks like
Main.js

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   tmp: 0,
 }
  this.accessTmp = this.accessTmp.bind(this)
}

accessTmp() {
  let tst = this.state.tmp
  alert(tst)
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <CustomSlider onChange= {this.accessTmp} />
      <Button onClick = {this.accessTmp} />

    </div>  
  )
}
```

Slider.js

```
const handle = props => {
   const { value, dragging, index, ...restProps } = props;
   return (
      <Tooltip
         prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
         overlay={value}
         visible={dragging}
         placement="top"
         key={index}
      >
         <Handle value={value} {...restProps} />
      </Tooltip>
   );
};

const Slider = props => {
   return (
      <div>
         <div style={{ width: 300, margin: 30 }}>
            <p>{this.props.title}</p>
            <Slider min={0} max={10} defaultValue={5} onChange={props.onChange} handle={handle}/>
         </div>
      </div>
   );
};

export default Slider;
```

Whenever I click the button 0 is alerted. However, when I move the slider I get `Cannot read property ‘tmp’ of undefined`

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Your `accessTmp` method just sets a local variable, and does nothing else. You won't be able to observe that this function has even run, without adding more code to it.

Comment: I notice you're nesting `Slider` within itself. Is this intended?

Comment: *Cannot read property ‘tmp’ of undefined* - you cannot physically get this from the code you posted. accessTmp is bound to `this`, and `this` has `state` object` which is not undefined. There's no place for error. Whatever the problem is, it's specific to differences in real code, the error could refer to different place. There are inconsistencies in the code, Slider is recursive and won't be able to render at all. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: You're probably encountering an infinite render loop which at some point terminates and gives you an undefined state value.

Comment: @estus Slider is successfully rendering. Its just when I am the changes the problem occurs. I have tested wheater slider is working or not by removing the `tst` variable and alerting the value of the slider, it does work. The problem occurs only when accessing tmp variable from the state

Comment: @KenoClayton any suggestions how I can avoid that

Comment: @toymoy *Slider is successfully rendering* - it is recursive, your code clearly differs from what you posted.  *alerting the value of the slider* - there's no slider value in the function, your code clearly differs from what you posted. I explained why the thing you describe isn't true for posted code. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. This is required by SO rules, otherwise the question is considered off-topic and can be closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . A demo at Stackblitz would help.

Comment: Your component is defined as `<Slider>` and you are again calling `<Slider>` inside of the return. Is that actually what you have in your code? I would expect either another component entirely or regular html tags.